# Eclipse CDT 10 - Refactor preview - Change background color of FILE selection (checkboxes)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to adjust the colors set by a theme for Eclipse CDT (my installation is Eclipse CDT 10.7 for Windows).

I set almost everything, but the background color of the file selection in refactor preview (or search & replace preview) is still wrong and I'm not able to figure the corresponding option (or an entry for a preference file) that set it.

I already searched on SO and with google. I found solutions for other cases but not for the my one.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this case? (see the picture)

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, Eclipse uses its internal settings, while in others, it defaults to the Windows settings. Additionally, Windows switches certain parameters between the classic color scheme and the visual style configuration depending on the current version of Windows ([see on github: Abdelrhman-AK/WinPaletter](https://github.com/Abdelrhman-AK/WinPaletter/issues/57)).

So, there is no single solution as it depends on the current version of Eclipse CDT and the installed version of Windows.

Note: The Eclipse CDT guys are working to address this issue, and some fixes may already be available. Unfortunately, I am unable to update the IDE at this time.

On Windows 10 22H2, I found a solution by copying and renaming the **aero.msstyles** file, and then modifying the renamed file by adding a **FILLCOLOR** property in the visual style class **DarkMode_Explorer::TreeView**. This also affects all Explorer instances when the Windows App Dark mode is active. Additionally, [WinPaletter](https://github.com/Abdelrhman-AK/WinPaletter) allows for refining the classic color scheme.

For more information see and use:

1. [msstyleEditor](https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor)
2. [SecureUxTheme](https://github.com/namazso/SecureUxTheme) (It HACK system files. You
   may not want use it).
3. [WinPaletter](https://github.com/Abdelrhman-AK/WinPaletter)

That said, I'm not familiar with setting visual styles so I'll leave the question open as I would prefer, if it exists, a less invasive solution.